# Pivot or Group Table with Multiple Dates as Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

With SQL Server, I would like to pivot or group multiple date columns per id like in the example below:

Four columns from table `[db].[exampletable]`, `Id`, `1/1`, `2/1`, `3/1`

| Id | 1/1 | 2/1 | 3/1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 117 | 10 | 5 | 20 |
| 118 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| 119 | 20 | 15 | 15 |
| 120 | 20 | 20 | 15 |

Desired Result:

| Id | date | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 117 | 1/1 | 10 |
| 117 | 2/1 | 5 |
| 117 | 3/1 | 20 |
| 118 | 1/1 | 5 |
| 118 | 2/1 | 10 |
| 118 | 3/1 | 15 |

Comment: this is a straight forward `UNPIVOT` (not PIVOT)

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses a union query:

```sql
SELECT Id, '1/1' AS date, [1/1] AS sum FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT id, '2/1', [2/1] FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT id, '3/1', [3/1] FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Id, date;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this put all of the sum values in the date columns as well as the sum column

Comment: @Starbucks This answer should be working for the sample data you provided.  Can you be more specific about what problem you see with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have variable or a growing number of columns, you can use a bit of JSON to dynamically UNPIVOT your data without having to use Dynamic SQL

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5b2d14b5dbd8ecb0c0a5d38e46e1eafd)**

```
Select A.[ID]
      ,B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select [date] = try_convert(varchar(25),[key])
                       ,[sum]  = try_convert(int,Value)
                 From OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                 Where [key] not in ('Id','OtherColumns','ToExclude')
              ) B
```